# Specify background opacity without specifying colour

Tags: html, css

How do you specify the *opacity* of a `background-color` without changing the existing background colour?

For example, consider:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.light {
  background-color: rgba(?, ?, ?, 0.9) /* <--- what do I use here? */
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue light"></div>
<div class="green light"></div>
```

What value can I provide in `div.light` to change the opacity without overriding/changing the green/blue colour?  Something like a `background-alpha` or `background-opacity` (which don't exist)

Edit: I don't want to change the opacity for the div *contents* at all; just the background.

Edit: I am aware there are solutions involving adding DOM, but this goes against design best practices (don't use DOM for styling) and I'm aiming for a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo elements for the backgrounds instead and use `opacity`

```css
div.blue::before {
  background-color: blue;
}

div.green::before {
  background-color: green;
}

div.light::before {
  background-color: rgba(?, ?, ?, 0.9)
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

.light::before {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">blue</div>
<div class="green">green</div>
<div class="blue light">blue light</div>
<div class="green light">green light</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't exist, but you can do a `div.background` with the full size of the div and a `div.content` with the text, images etc and add `opacity to div.background`